# why doesn't the pptplex tab appear in the powerpoint ribbon?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I've installed pptPlex but it doesn't appear in the powerpoint ribbon.

I tried reviewing the security settings, but maybe I've missed something. I have windows-7 and powerpoint 2007

Comment: What's pptPlex and where'd you get it?  A URL might help others help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the service pack for office and the latest .NET Framework